# How to only remove the house/building number from an address column using python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a column of addresses in my dataframe. I want to remove the house number from the strings and use only the street name to make a treemap or wordcloud.
However, there are addresses which have sometime 3 digits or sometimes more before the street name. Also, some street names have numbers in themselves so I can't use %d to remove the numbers in str.split or regex. I recently started learning python so I don't know how to split this kind of string. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is an example of addresses given in the column:
3150 N HONORE ST
139 E 103RD ST
412 E LOWER WACKER DR
300 E 94TH ST
10340 S AVENUE J
619 S KEDVALE AVE

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all house addresses do not have a space in them, you could split the string by the first space. An example of usage:

```
s="3150 N Honore St"
new_s=s.split(" ",1)[1]
```

To break that down - `s.split(" ",1)` splits the string at the first space, but only 1 time. This will form a list of the string, that would look like `['3150','N Honore St']`. Since you only want the latter portion, the `[1]` selects it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an regular expression: `^\d*\s`

https://regex101.com/r/B7DbxW/1

Comment: It works if I using it on a string object but how do I make it work on a column of a data set or series?                                                                        
 address = df["Street Address"]                                                          
 regex2 = r"^\d*\s"                                                                                                matches2 = re.finditer(regex2, address, re.MULTILINE)                                    I get the below error when I run matches2                                      TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Loop trough every row and parse the string

Comment: I tried looping through the rows and adding the strings to a list but it didn't work                                                                                                                   l = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    matches2 = re.finditer(regex2, row["Street Address"])
    l.append(matches2)                                                                                          when I print l get <callable-iterator at 0xdd0a0f0> in each instance instead of string of street name

Answer (score 0):

I just started out with regular expressions in Python but here's my try:

```
\d+\s[A-Z]\s+(.+)
```

Here's a quick link if you want to see the matches: https://regex101.com/r/rzNgTL/1